# Prove that $a^n \cdot a^m = a^{n+m}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $a$ be an element of a group $G$. Prove that $a^n \cdot a^m = a^{n+m}$  for any integers $m,n \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: What have you tried to do? HINT: Expand $a^n$ and $a^m$ using the definition of $a^x$, $x\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I tried to do induction on $m$ and separated into two parts $m > 0$ and $m<0$

Comment: Nimda's answer is what my hint was going for... expand $a^n$ to $n$ $a$'s being multiplied together and $a^m$ to $m$ $a$'s being multiplied together. Now, how many $a$ factors are there?

Comment: induction over n or m

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just think of $a^n$ as the product $\underbrace{a\textbf{.}a\textbf{.}\ldots\textbf{.}a}_{\text{n factors}}$ and what happens  when you multiply it with a product with $\text{m factors}$.

Comment: You have to be careful with this argument, because it only applies when $n$ is at least $0$ (as written, it makes no sense to have -3 factors, for instance). The case for negative $n$ and $m$ is of course very similar, but does need to be dealt with separately.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $n \geq 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we use finite induction on $n$.

For $n=0$ we have

$$ a^m * a^0 = a^m * e_G = a^m = a^{m+0}.$$

Suppose now that $n=k$, $a^{m+k} = a^m * a^k$ is true (by induction  hypothesis).

And finally we have

$$
     a^m*a^{k+1} = a^m*(a^k*a) = (a^m * a^k ) * a = a^{m+k} * a = a^{(m+k)+1} = a^{m+(k+1)}.
$$

For equality $a^{n+m} = a^n*a^m$. Suposse $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, and we chose $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p>0$ and $p+n>0$, so

$$
a^{m+n} = a^{m+n} * e_G = a^{m+n} * (a^p * a^{-p}) = (a^{m+n} * a^p) * a^{-p} = a^{m+n+p} * a^{-p} = (a^m * a^{n+p}) * a^{-p} = (a^m*(a^n * a^p))*a^{-p} = (a^m * a^n) * (a^p * a^{-p}) = (a^m * a^n) * e_G = a^m * a^n.
$$